# plotting MDS in R with text

Tags: r, text, plot

I have a simple PLINK MDS "Cauc71.mds" :

```
    FID         IID     SOL     C1              C2 
1   Lezgins     lez37   0       0.0196617       0.0366344 
2   Georgians   mg47    0       0.0121934       -0.0335062 
    ...
71  Kumyk       Kumyk22 0       0.00135308      0.00216335
```

The following code will produce a plot in R :

```
d <- read.table("Cauc71.mds", header=TRUE)
plot(d$C1, d$C2, pch=20, cex=2, col = d$SOL+1)
```

Is there a simple way to use text-labels from the **IID** column {**lez37**, **mg47** *etc* } instead of the pch points?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO: please format the code properly and provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Ali Yes, as a result of the comment now it is ;D (see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21114096/revisions)

Comment: sorry for the sloppy 1st-post; very prompt and useful responses

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define this in `plot`. You can only plot points, lines etc. But you could add the text afterwards, e.g.

```
text(d$C1, d$C2, labels=d$IID, col = d$SOL+1)
```

Additionally, you will probably need to position the text properly using the parameters `pos` or `adj`.

If you also want to get rid of the points, you could add the argument `type="n"` to the plot function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d <- read.table("Cauc71.mds", header=TRUE)
plot(d$C1, d$C2, pch=20, cex=0, col = d$SOL+1)
text(d$C1, d$C2, labels=d$IID)
```

You can also use the ggplot2 package to generate better plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=C1, y=C2, label=IID))+geom_text()
```

[image]